# newbie trying to write url rewrite in .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My site was under `example.com/waha/`.
Now I move the site right under the root `example.com`.

I want to 301 redirect all the old links like `example.com/waha/notice/5803` to `example.com/notice/5803`.

How can I do it?

My current .htaccess file is below.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # NOTE: change this to your actual StatusNet path; may be "/".

  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "\.(ini)">
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>
Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule in front of your other mod_rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^waha/(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi Gumbo, it seems like you are expert in this, can you help me with [this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13215552/what-is-wrong-with-this-htaccess-code)