# What is wrong with this .htaccess code?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to change article and profile links in my site to dynamic ones. i.e.

- **for article**: `site.com/article.php?id=12`  becomes `site.com/article/this_is_title_of_article`
- **for profile**: `site.com/ref.php?user=23` becomes `site.com/john_doe`

So I wrote this to `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ref.php?user=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^articles/(.*)$ article.php?user=$1 [QSA,L]
```

So, for the profile it works. You can type `site.com/username`, and it works. But, for the articles it does not- it just does not display anything.

I can't understand why if username is more than one word, it does not add underscores between the words: even if I add to the URL like `site.com/john_doe` it won't work.

So, pretty much, the above code works only for username AND if that username is only one word.

Comment: Did you actually name your file `.htacess`? If so, then rename it to `.htaccess`.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. The name is fine. After all, the code is partially working with the profile re-writing

Comment: Hi Danny, I wish I knew what that meant. I have pasted all that is there in the .htaccess above and I am using XAMPP in my localhost. I don't know about rewritebase though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules are evaluated from top to bottom, so most likely your user rule is catching everything before your articles rule gets a chance.

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^articles/(.*)$ article.php?user=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ref.php?user=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I tried it and somehow the site got defaced. half of the CSS does not work and the same for the articles who do not show up.

Comment: That's probably because your CSS links are referencing the current folder (which is now `articles/`). Change them from `href="filename"` to `href="/filename"` so that they are relative to the root of your website domain.

Comment: I put a little effort to illustrate the problem and uploaded this image (http://imm.io/KnMe) please check it and tell me what you think. I made the site by myself so that might be the problem

Comment: Seriously you should consider trying a basic php framework like [Codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/) rather than putting sql in your html like that. From your screenshot I don't know what you're asking me though.